What made Einstein to think time also dilates, along with space, with increasing gravity?
Michelson–Morley experiment showed that speed of the light remains same regardless of speed of observer. Based on it Albert Einstein came up with the proposal of time dilation for object in speed (otherwise there is no way one can justify constant speed of light). That was base of Special Relativity.
But in General Relativity, when he discovers equivalence of acceleration and gravity, he came up with proposal that this can be better explained by sheer geometry, especially warping of space. Thus he said, if we view gravity as curvature of space (instead of force) things can be explained better (e.g. anomalous precession of Mercury's orbit)
My question is, what made Einstein to think time also dilates with increasing gravity (just like it does with increasing velocity)? Because bending of light due to gravity (which supports time dilation, as light has to travel more when bent but it's speed remains same, hence dilation of time) was observed much later (in solar eclipse that happened 1919) after his formation of theory of General Relativity.

What precisely in this tangled mess do you actually want an answer to? After SR, it became clear to every scientist who had understood SR, that space alone or time alone is just nonsense, and the only thing that can be correct, is spacetime. In the Schwarzchild black hole, most of the bending is of time, not of space.

@naturallyInconsistent In SR there's no curvature of space involved. But is length contraction what made scientists to think space alone or time alone is just nonsense? And is that the same reason why Einstein considered time dilation along with curvature of space in gravity?

"Because bending of light due to gravity (which supports time dilation, as light has to travel more when bent but it's speed remains same, hence dilation of time)": this is  nonsense, light travels the same distance in the same time, regardless of moving in a straight line or not.

@PatoGalmarini If not straight line, the distance would increase. Given that speed of light remains constant, we need to increase (dilate) time.

If you understood SR, you will understand that it is the entirety of SR that requires spacetime to be treated as one thing, not two parts. Length contraction is only one small piece of the puzzle. Once you see spacetime as one thing, it makes no sense to even think of curving space alone without curving time too.

@user1976551 "If not straight line, the distance would increase. " This is wrong, the light can go straight or in a circle, but it will cover a light year in a year, that is, the same distance in both cases.

@PatoGalmarini If bending of space doesn't explain time dilation, how can time dilation be explained in gravity by sheer geometry?

If light is close to a strong gravitational source, it cannot escape, even if moving in the opposite direction. It would appear to you--at some distance--that the light was frozen in time, that time has dilated to zero (actually the light wouldn't be observable but we're simplifying things for now). However, if you went to the light's position with your clock, you would see your clock ticking normally.

This is a direct consequence of the Einstein equivalence principle, which states that being stationary in a uniform gravitational field $g$ is equivalent to being in a reference frame with proper acceleration $g$ in the absence of gravity. This alone implies that gravitational time dilation must exist. The bending of light is not necessary.

Proof 1
Light moving against a gravitational field is equivalent to light moving from the rear to the front of an accelerating spaceship in the absence of gravity. By the classical Doppler effect (all relativistic corrections are second order and above), we can conclude that the light is redshifted upon reaching the receiver at the front. This implies that the receiver observes the source's clock running slow, which means that clocks higher up in a gravitational well run faster than clocks lower down.
Proof 2
Consider the twin paradox setup between A and B. Twin A is inertial while twin B moves away while accelerating at $g$ back towards twin A, eventually arriving back at A. The equivalence principle implies that this situation is identical to the situation in which B stands on the surface of the Earth (which has proper acceleration $g$) while A is launched upwards with an impulse and subsequently freefalls back to B. Since the accelerating twin, B, is younger than A, it must be true that A, who spends time higher up in the Earth's gravitational field, experiences more time.

Both of the above proofs are given in chapter 14 of Morin's Introduction to Classical Mechanics: With Problems and Solutions.

"gravitational time dilation must exist. The bending of light is not necessary"... this says it! many thanks. btw, is this applicable only as long as object is accelerating in gravity (free fall)? what about time dilation when object is not accelerating but still is in immense gravity?

@user1976551 The EEP applies as long as you consider sufficiently small regions of spacetime. If the object is moving then the time dilation will change as well. Gravitational time dilation is proportional to first order to the difference in gravitational potential.

Gravitational time dilation comes out of the solutions to the Einstein field equations, ultimately. But a heuristic reason to expect it is that light rising in a gravitational field must lose energy, and hence frequency. This gravitational redshift means that a higher observer will view the lower observers clocks as ticking slowly.
